# how to parse jsonArray i m getting this error , while fetching Json Data

Tags: arrays, json, kotlin, retrofit

Execption at Runtime `JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY"`

This is Actual json i want to fetch

```
{
    "id": 414,
    "origin_station_code": 5,
    "station_path":[ 58,68,72,86],
    "destination_station_code": 93,
    "date": "03/12/2022 01:25 PM",
    "map_url": "https://picsum.photos/200",
    "state": "Arunachal Pradesh",
    "city": "Pasighat"
}
```

My Data Class

```
data class Rides(
@SerializedName("id") var id: Int? = null,
@SerializedName("origin_station_code") var origin_station_code: Int? = null,
@SerializedName("station_path") var destination_station_code: Int? = null,
@SerializedName("destination_station_code") var station_path: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(),
@SerializedName("date") var date: String? = null,
@SerializedName("map_url") var map_url: String? = null,
@SerializedName("state") var city: String? = null,
@SerializedName("city") var state: String? = null,
```

)

What should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error tells you that the response actually begins with `[` instead of `{` so I suspect that you are actually getting a list of these `Rides` objects.

I see you have

```
@GET("/rides")
suspend fun getAllRides() : RidesResponse
```

and `RidesResponse` is

```
data class RidesResponse(
    val results : List<Rides>
)
```

Now you basically are telling it that the respons should look like

```
{
    "results": [
      ...
    ]
}
```

but you don't have that. So I think you should just change the api to

```
@GET("/rides")
suspend fun getAllRides() : List<Rides>
```

Comment: please have a look at my code https://github.com/ashgautamDev/EdvoraRides/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/ashish/edvorarides/data/api/RidesApi.kt , well i have used List<Rides>

Comment: @AshishGautam see the edit

Comment: Now i m getting , Expected an int but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 53 path $[0].station_path

Comment: @AshishGautam you somehow mixed up the `SerializedName` of `station_path` and `destination_station_code`.